# air for android drag performance

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, air

I'm developing an android application by AS3.. and what I want to do is to add a slider on the main screen for user to choose different settings. but the performance is very slow. Im not using any gesture event..

I used drag and drop and then I used enter_frame listeners to increase the performance.. but its all catching the finger so late..

Is there any method that I can increase the performance? I also want to use this method to slide between pages, like native android screen.. But its not even moving when i tried that.. is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried instead to use a view flipper?

Comment: I dont know what is view flipper.. Is it special AS3 class or event?